# Chrome autofill: first & last name?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

Is it a way to separate first / last name in Chrome autofill? Currently it shows only the name field. 
[image]

Yet many sites didn't heard about benefits of giving only one field for name vs two fields. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### use *autocomplete attributes*

Use any of these for autocomplete:

- `name` (for full name)
- `given-name` (for first name)
- `additional-name` (for middle name)
- `family-name` (for last name)

  ```
    Example: <input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="given-name">
  ```

This way, you can have the desired info autofilled in the user's form.

Also, here's the [recommended guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values) for all other input fields too.

Comment: This is nice to know for web-devs, but I believe the OP wanted to know if there is a way to tell Chrome what's what. Currently it seems Chrome splits the name on whitespace, adds the first word to given-name, the last to family-, and the rest to additional-. Which is a poor assumption, making the autofill less useful.

Comment: Here also a handy reference for other possible fields: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Answer (score 4):

The answer from [Superole](https://superuser.com/a/1517947/499650) set me on the path for finding the answer. Unfortunately the Alt+code only works on Windows. So here I will focus on a more general case and then on Linux.

[Here](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0kYFO3yFe5Z8/?hl=es-419) Simone explains:

> You could consider inserting a non-breaking space into your surname.
>
> 1. Find a Unicode encoder/decoder online, for example [this](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php)
> 2. Insert your name as text and convert it to a unicode string. Taking your example "Leonard James Akaar" will be converted into
>      "Leonard%20James%20Akaar"
> 3. Change the last space (Unicode %20) to a non-breaking space (Unicode %A0). The result will look like this
>      "Leonard%20James%A0Akaar"
> 4. Convert it back to text. You will see "Leonard James Akaar" again, but this time the first and the second space are different characters,
>      and the autofiller will recognize "James Akaar" as a single word.
> 5. Copy the text you obtained
> 6. Open settings -> advanced -> passwords and forms -> autofill settings -> edit. Replace your name with the edited one.

However in my case, when I copy the line with the invisible character from the browser my clipboard seems to change it for an space, so when I paste the line on Chrome settings it doesn't change anything. So save yourself some time and paste the result back into the same [translator](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) page to verify.

One workaround I found for Linux is:

1. Open a console / terminal
2. Open a python interpreter

```
# python
```

3. Inside it, execute this (modify the location of \u00A0 to your needs

```
# print(u"Name Surname1\u00A0Surname2")
```

4. Copy the result with the mouse > right click

[image]

Now that string contains the invisible character. You can use the translator page to verify it.

[image]

Finally, you can use these forms to verify if the autofill works as expected

- http://www.passwordmanager.co.uk/test.htm
- https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields

Note: Simon mentioned "%A0" but I needed a code for python. [Here](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) I found the translation table.

[image: %A0 windows character into unicode]

More descriptive title so others can find it: How to make Chrome browser autofill feature handle correctly two surnames, multiple surnames, multiple names, two names, complex names when filling / autofilling online forms.

Comment: This is a really good solution for even a final user, maybe google should take a look at this for further documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a sort of workaround that seems to trick Chrome's splitting algorithm.

In the edit address form (chrome://settings/addresses -> more -> edit) you can replace the spaces that are not "name separators" with the character that you get when you hold down<kbd>Alt</kbd>, type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> on the numeric keypad, and then release the <kbd>Alt</kbd>button.

E.g. for given-name "Kaare Bjarne" and family-name "Van der Kurt" you would get:

```
Kaare Bjarne Van der Kurt
```

...and Chrome now seems to autofill it correctly :)

On this page you can test your settings quickly: https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields

Comment: Note that this non-breaking-space character sometimes gets converted to a normal space, when you copy/paste it...